# How to use encog AI for 3D dataset

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, accelerometer, encog

I have `dataset` from `accelerometer` that consist of 3 vectors `(x, y, z)`
The issue is that examples on Encog library are for `XOR` problem and use 2 dimension, and `MLData` accept only one dimension - double[].

Can anyone help me in explain on `3D dataset` or
to point me any other library where is possible to utilize 3D dataset?

**EDITED**

OK what I did to make it work is

```
public float compareTwoSequences(HashMap<Integer,List<Float>> base,
                                          HashMap<Integer,List<Float>> compare){
    Log.i("NN alg", "comparing two Sequences");

    List<Float> baseX = base.get(SensorData.X_axis);
    List<Float> baseY = base.get(SensorData.Y_axis);
    List<Float> baseZ = base.get(SensorData.Z_axis);
    List<Float> compareX = compare.get(SensorData.X_axis);
    List<Float> compareY = compare.get(SensorData.Y_axis);
    List<Float> compareZ = compare.get(SensorData.Z_axis);

    int baseSize = baseX.size();
    int compSize = compareX.size();
    int minSize = Math.min(baseSize, compSize);

    double[][] dataSet = new double[6][minSize];
    double[][] testSet = new double[3][minSize];
    double[][] ideal = new double[][]{
            {2.0},
            {2.0},
            {2.0},
            {0.0},
            {0.0},
            {0.0}
    };
    double[][] idealTest = new double[][]{
            {1.0},
            {1.0},
            {1.0}
    };

    Iterator<Float> xIter = baseX.iterator();
    Iterator<Float> yIter = baseY.iterator();
    Iterator<Float> zIter = baseZ.iterator();
    Iterator<Float> xIter1 = compareX.iterator();
    Iterator<Float> yIter1 = compareY.iterator();
    Iterator<Float> zIter1 = compareZ.iterator();
    for(int i = 0; i < minSize; i++){
        testSet[0][i] = dataSet[0][i] = xIter.next();
        testSet[1][i] = dataSet[1][i] = yIter.next();
        testSet[2][i] = dataSet[2][i] = zIter.next();
        dataSet[3][i] = xIter1.next();
        dataSet[4][i] = yIter1.next();
        dataSet[5][i] = zIter1.next();
    }


    NeuralDataSet trainingSet = new BasicNeuralDataSet(dataSet,ideal);

    network = new BasicNetwork();
    network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(null, false, baseSize));
    network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, 7));
    network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, 7));
    network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationLinear(), false, 1));
    network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
    network.reset();

    final Propagation train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);



    int epochsCount = 100;
        for(int epoch = 1; epoch > epochsCount; epoch++ ){
            train.iteration();
        }
        Log.i("alg NN","Training error: "+train.getError()*100.0);
        train.finishTraining();

        int i=0;
        double error = 0.0;
        while(i<6){
            MLData input = new BasicMLData(dataSet[i]);
            MLData output = network.compute(input);
            if(i<3){
                error += Math.abs(output.getData(0));
            }
            Log.i("alg NN","Classification for i:"+i+" "+output.getData(0)+ " ideal "+ideal[i][0]);
            i++;
        }

        error = error/3.0*100.0;
        Log.i("alg NN","Final error is: "+error);
        return (float)(error);
}
```

Anyway I will try now to calibrate network, because the results are bad - like the corresctess is under 50%, where by DTW algorithm is about 80%-90%.

Basicaly I did

```
input[][]=new double[][]{
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, // x Axis - first gesture
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, // y Axis - first gesture
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, // z Axis - first gesture
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, // x Axis - second gesture 
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, // y Axis - second gesture 
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, // z Axis - second gesture 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (this is C#, but Java should be similar)

```
    double[][] Input =
    {
            new[] {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            new[] {1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
            new[] {0.0, 1.0, 2.0},
            new[] {1.0, 1.0, 3.0}
    };

    double[][] Ideal =
    {
            new[] {0.0},
            new[] {1.0},
            new[] {1.0},
            new[] {0.0}
    };

    Encog.ML.Data.Basic.BasicMLDataSet TrainingSet = new Encog.ML.Data.Basic.BasicMLDataSet(Input, Ideal);
```

Note that each of the inputs contains three values.  This is adapted from an XOR problem, but I have added an extra value to each, so that each row simulates a single accelerometer input.

Comment: Nice I will try it, and then evaluate coretnesss of the answer. By the way have you used unsupervised training?
By default the constructor is with two parameters new `BasicNeuralDataSet(dataset, ideal);`
there is method such `trainingSet.add(MLData)` but _MLData_ is interface and I cannot just create _MLData_ before with _double[][] input_

Comment: I mean that MLData allowed to `set(double[])` no _double[][]_ , do you know any way to make it functional?